# Laravel Elixir - SASS Watch on a Custom Path?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I'm having an issue with watching custom paths with Laravel Elixir's sass.

Here is the code.

```
var publicScss = [
    './resources/assets/scss/public',
    './resources/assets/jquery_plugins/rotate.scss'
];

elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.sass(publicScss, './public_html/css/dist/public.css');

    // Tried the suggested solution below, but it still doesn't watch the files
    // https://github.com/laravel/elixir/issues/297
    elixir.Task.find('sass').watch(publicScss);

    mix.browserSync();
});
```

The SCSS files get compiled to CSS if I just do `gulp`. But with `gulp watch` it doesn't seem to watch for changes.

Anyone else had setting up a sass watcher on a custom path?

Answer (score 4):

After spending some more time on this, I realised just entering a directory path to watch doesn't work. You have to either explicitly specify the filenames or enter a wildcard.

The following works:

```
var publicScss = [
    './resources/assets/scss/public/*.scss',
    './resources/assets/jquery_plugins/rotate.scss'
];

elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.sass(publicScss, './public_html/css/dist/public.css');

    // the watch needs to receive a filename or a wildcard (not a directory)
    elixir.Task.find('sass').watch(publicScss);

    mix.browserSync();
});
```

Comment: You save my life !! :)